# Minimum Gas limit and how can it be reduced?

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-limit, zksnark

Why does this minimum exist and what can we do to to reduce it further. This line of thought was spurred by this tweet from Vitalik:

> "And there are layer 2's without data availability tradeoffs or liveness requirements, eg. tx mass-validation via ZK-SNARKs can reduce costs to < 1000 gas per tx if done well. That's ~500 tx/sec on-chain with all the security guarantees of on-chain."

I did a quick search through [the yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) and there is no break down of the contributing factors to this. just

```
Gtransaction 21000 Paid for every transaction.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is for the Ethereum fallback function. Basically, it's there to prevent people from accidentally sending Ether to a contract irrevocably.

Answer (score 0):

Gtransaction is a so called intrinsic transaction cost, i.e. amount of gas paid by transaction initiator for the transaction to be processed in addition to any gas paid for EVM bytecode executed during transaction processing.  Normal on-chain transaction cannot cost less than Gtransaction.

Though, off-chain transactions, such as Plasma transaction, or transactions validated en-masse via zero knowledge proofs may consume much less gas, in theory less then 1 gas unit per transaction.  This is possible because arbitrary number of such transactions may be verified by one, or a few of on-chain transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to send ETh without a gas fee also. You would ask users to first sign a message on the front end. Then the message and signature would be sent to a centralized backend (your app, off-chain) that would create a transaction and embed the payload (message + signature) into it. That means that gas fees will be covered by the wallet of the app, instead of the user wallet. On-chain, a smart contract will verify the validity of the signature and perform on operation on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 0):

As of the writing of this answer, all Ethereum transactions must pay a 21000 "intrinsic gas fee" that essentially accounts for the computation required to process any transaction regardless of the effects of the rest of this transaction.

Examples of computation required for every transaction regardless of size or computation:

- Reducing the user's balance by the fee paid
- Increasing the miner's balance by the priority fee paid
- Reducing the total available gas in the gas pool for a given block

Not a complete list by any measure, but the general idea is there: all transactions require *some* level of computation. If transactions didn't require any intrinsic gas, you could spam transactions all you wanted. Of course there's a case to be made that 21000 might be too high or too low, it's interesting that the number hasn't been changed yet.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum gas requirement ensures that miners are compensated for their work, even for simple transactions. And also, it can prevent network spam. Without a minimum gas requirement, malicious actors could flood the network with a large number of tiny transactions, which would consume computational resources and make it difficult for legitimate transactions to get processed in a timely manner.